# Create polygon using ST_GeomFromText

Tags: mysql, variables, polygon, point

I'm trying to create a polygon and in MySQL the way to do it is by using ST_GeomFromText (POLYGON (') from what I've seen, but I need to be able to use variables instead of just a string.

Ex. instead of

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571,-71.1776820268866 42.3903701743239,
-71.1776063012595 42.3903825660754,-71.1775826583081 42.3903033653531,-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571))');
```

Use something like

```
SET @p1 = POINT(-71.1776585052917, 42.3902909739571);
SET @p2 = POINT(-71.1776820268866, 42.3903701743239);
SET @p3 = POINT(-71.1776063012595, 42.3903825660754);
SET @p4 = POINT(-71.1775826583081, 42.3903033653531);

SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p1)');
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?
P.S. My first time asking a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but the way i fixed it was using this method.

```
    SET @p1 = ST_GeometryFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',(lat-@POINT_DISTANCE),' ',(lon+@POINT_DISTANCE),')'), 4326);
    SET @p2 = ST_GeometryFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',(lat+@POINT_DISTANCE),' ',(lon+@POINT_DISTANCE),')'), 4326);
    SET @p3 = ST_GeometryFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',(lat+@POINT_DISTANCE),' ',(lon-@POINT_DISTANCE),')'), 4326);
    SET @p4 = ST_GeometryFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',(lat-@POINT_DISTANCE),' ',(lon-@POINT_DISTANCE),')'), 4326);

    SET @str = CONCAT('POLYGON((',
        ST_X(@p1),
        ' ',
        ST_Y(@p1),
        ',',
        ST_X(@p2),
        ' ',
        ST_Y(@p2),
        ',',
        ST_X(@p3),
        ' ',
        ST_Y(@p3),
        ',',
        ST_X(@p4),
        ' ',
        ST_Y(@p4),
        ',',
        ST_X(@p1),
        ' ',
        ST_Y(@p1),

     '))');

SET @POLY = ST_GeomFromText(@str, 4326);
     
SELECT id FROM user_details force index(user_details_location) WHERE ST_CONTAINS(@POLY, user_details.location);
```

Basically just a lot of concatenations, and it seems to work.